# How to start a *.batch file in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, batch-file, delphi-7

When I run the `L.bat` it launches any application successfully.

`L.bat` code:

```
@ECHO OFF
start notepad.exe
exit
```

When I use my application, designed and compiled in Delphi 7 the `L.bat` isn't running.

Code inside my app:

```
procedure TFMain.ImgBtn1Click( Sender: TObject );
begin
  Dir := GetCurrentDir ;
  RunApp( Dir + 'L.bat' );
  FMain.Close;
end;
```

Comment: What does `RunApp` do? It's not a Delphi RTL function. If we can't see how it tries to launch the batch file, it's pretty difficult to tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your `RunApp` function doesn't use Windows Shell for opening a file. But you shouldn't bother with batch files and execute that notepad.exe directly from your app.

Comment: Shure you want to use GetCurrentDir? 1.) is the batch file at this place 2. You would have to use Dir:=IncludeTrailingBackSlash(GetCurrentDir);

Comment: I am using the batch file because i want to run another application with parameters. Like if the application i want to launch is cabalmain.exe(online game, im creating launchers), the batch file (L.bat) is used to launch cabalmain.exe with this parameter: cabalmain.exe zds_30 and it successfully launches it if i just double click it.

Comment: I found the solution: i used:     `ShellExecute(TForm(Owner).Handle,nil,PChar('L.bat'), nil, nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);` and it worked.

Comment: If the only reason to execute batch files is that you want to run an application with parameters, then you didn't find a solution but a weak way to do so. Even `ShellExecute` has a parameter for specifying execution parameters, so e.g. with this  `ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'cabalmain.exe, 'zds_30', nil, SW_SHOW);` you'll get rid of that batch file. But there are also other ways to execute an application with parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `cmd.exe /c` to run batch files. So `RunApp('cmd.exe /c "'+Dir+'\L.bat"');` should work.

Comment: i get I/O error 123 using this method